# Why do my html form elements tags not work within the <script> tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I just started learning javascript and was trying to execute this code in the body tag:

```
<script>
<form>
    <input type="button" value="Touch me!" onclick="alert('Hello');alert('It me');"/>
</form>
</script>
```

But it wouldn't work. It was only when I removed the script tags I had placed at the start and end of the code did it execute properly.If it executes alert, which is a javascript function, should it not need a `<script>` tag?

Comment: What were the "tags I had placed at the start and end of the code"?

Comment: By any chance, are you trying to say that you put `<script>` tags INSIDE the onclick?  that would be wrong.

Comment: Or are you wrapping your entire form within a `<script>` tag? That would be wrong, too. Anyway, you’re using inline script handlers. _That’s wrong, too._

Comment: I apologise for the question being unclear. Edited it with the appropriate changes. The entire form was indeed within the <script> tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not add `<Script>` tags in the onclick attribute of the button. Here you are specifying the javascript which will be executed. To be more clear:

```
<form>
    <input type="button" value="Touch me!" onclick="ExecuteTwoAlerts()"/>
</form>
```

Now you are saying, when the "Client" click this button execute this function. Now you should add this function in the script for this page, to ensure calling it on client click. Now you need the script tags, but in another way:

```
<form>
    <input type="button" value="Touch me!" onclick="ExecuteTwoAlerts()"/>
</form>
<script>
   function ExecuteTwoAlerts()
   {
       alert('1');
       alert('2');
   }
</script>
```

**In your case alert is already build in javascript function in the browser, so you executed it, without placing it in the script tags of the page. Same function is `confirm('confirm me')`**

Answer (score 0):

Check this example:
https://jsfiddle.net/ahLykhov/

```
<form>
    <input type="button" value="Touch me!" onclick="alert('Hello');alert('It me');"/>
</form>
```

Everything is fine with the code.
Maybe there is another problem?

Please post more details

Comment: This isn't an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
<form>
    <input type="button" value="Touch me!" onclick="funcEvent();"/>
</form>
<script>
    function funcEvet(){
    alert('Hello, It me');
  }
</script>
```

Or:

```
<form>
    <input id="btn" type="button" value="Touch me!"/>
  </form>
  <script>
    var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
    btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
      alert('Hello, It me');
    });
  </script>
```

Is not recommended to use javascript events into HTML labels.

Answer (score 0):

It works.

Just create a file with .html extension and paste there

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<form>
    <input type="button" value="Touch me!" onclick="alert('Hello');alert('It me');"/>
</form>
```

save it, then open it in Chrome or Firefox.
New HTML5 standard provides rules of how browsers render pages with minimum information (like example above). Your browser will add all the other necessary tags (like html, body, etc.)

You can also try:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <input type="button" value="Touch me!" onclick="alert('Hello');alert('It me');"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

which is a more extended and correct variant of your page.